# getting unique results without using group by

Tags: sql, sqlite

For some reason, I am not able to use `GROUP BY` but I can use `DISTINCT` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name), id, email from myTable
```

However above query lists people with same name also because I am selecting more than one columns whereas I want to select only unique names. Is there someway to get unique names without using `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: You need to decide which data (i.e. id) you want to keep if there are duplicate names with different id's. The first? The last? The average?

Comment: I am just looking to get unique names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although using `GROUP BY` is the most direct way, you can do other things if it is prohibited. For example, you can use `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT name, id, email
FROM myTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable tt WHERE tt.name=t.name AND tt.id < t.id)
```

This query uses `NOT EXISTS` to eliminate rows with the same name and IDs higher than the one selected. Note that since this query must pick a single user per name, it may eliminate some users based on their ID, which is a rather arbitrary criterion.